# CollectionView cells appearing outside collectionView.

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I have a collectionView laid out in the storyboard like so:

[image]

Note the constraint: Collection View.top = Search Bar.bottom

I don't want any of the content in the collection View above that line. However when the app runs and you scroll the collectionView, this is what happens to the cells. What could be happening here?

[image]

Comment: checked if the collection's top constraint has a minus constant value ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan no it doesn't. Also when I draw a background on the collectionView it is drawn in the proper place below the search bar. Its only when scroll happens that the cells/view moves up above the search bar

Comment: can you share a demo of it

Comment: @Sh_Khan ah! I had disabled "Clip to Bounds" on the collectionView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `collectionView.clipsToBounds = true`